# Unable to find definition for this Carbon/Apple Events Error

Tags: applescript, macos-mojave, appleevents

Can anyone tell me where I can find Carbon Error `-1743`? I have an AppleEvent I'm sending from one app to another that's worked up to this point but fails in Mojave.

Comment: The error is `errAEEventNotPermitted`. Please see https://www.felix-schwarz.org/blog/2018/06/apple-event-sandboxing-in-macos-mojave

Comment: This definitely is the problem, but for whatever reason when I try to send an AppleEvent I don't get the permission prompt, even after the `tccutil` database has been reset.

Answer (score 0):

As @vandian points out, this error is `errAEEventNotPermitted`, however, the security system won't ask you for permission to allow sending events unless you have a `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` key in your application's Info.plist.

So, the solution in my case was to add this key to Info.plist. This having been done, I got the permission prompt, and the event fired and was received by the other app.